# What does this operator <> mean in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What does the '<>' mean?

```
if ($class->stuff <> 'specific')
```

Just working on a little project and came across a strange symbol.

Comment: it's a comparator operator, meaning "not equals"

Answer (score 3):

It means:

> different

and is equivalent to `!=`

You can see a [table with all comparison operators here](http://br.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

Literally, "less than or greater than", meaning "not equal to"